# React trigger event through mouse click on span

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in react application and have an span in my code and there I placed the smilie icon. On click of span I want to trigger the `window + >` event.

**On chrome in windows platform this shortcut i.e `window + >` windows + period key will open the emoji's. I want to to trigger that through span click**

My code:

```
<span style={{position: "absolute"}} onClick={(e) => this.getTrigger(e)}>&#128522;</span>
```

Function written just above the render() in react.

```
getTrigger = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // let getEvent = document.addEventListener('mousedown');
    alert('event Clicked', getEvent)
    // I need to trigger the window + > event here
  }
```

What I have found is basically detection of key.

```
if(e.keyCode === '13') {
 //do something
}
```

But I need to fire/trigger the event not get detection.

I also get the way to be done but not able to resolve this:

```
// Event listener
document.addEventListener("eventName", function(e) {
  console.log(e.detail);
});

// Event create
let event = new CustomEvent("eventName", { "detail": "Event creation" });

// Dispatch/Trigger/Fire the event
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Can anyone guide me how to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried using `useRef()`?

Comment: What do you mean by `window + >` event?

Comment: `keyCode` is deprecated, prefer [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) or [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code). Are you just looking for `onKeyDown`?

Comment: @Chris windows button + period button. On chrome in windows platform this shortcut will open the emoji's. I want to to trigger that though span call

Comment: Then post that as your question.

Comment: You need to listen on keydown / keypress/ keyup and the show the emoji by updating a state property.

Comment: Added the mouse event detection, but how to trigger the combination of keys event